# Перескающиеся прямоугольники

Tags: c#, геометрия

Всем привет

Решаю такую задачу:

Пусть для каждого прямоугольника заданы:

```
1. Уникальная метка прямоугольника, например "#123",
2. Расстояние от левого и верхнего края картины, например "3,2",
3. Ширина и высота прямоугольника, например "5x4",
```

Таким образом, запись "#123 @ 3,2: 5x4" означает, прямоугольник #123 расположен в 3см от левого края, в 2см от верхнего края, имеет 5см в ширину и 4см в высоту.

1)Найти суммарную площадь пересечений (считая каждое пересечение 1 раз)

2)Как оказалось, ровно 1 прямоугольник не пересекается ни с одним другим. Найдите его и выведите метку.

Написал код для решения:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace ConsoleApp5
{
    class Program
    {
        struct rectangle
        {
            public int _id;
            public int _x_left, _y_left;
            public int _x_right, _y_right;
            public bool _crossing;
        }

        static int _sum_of_crossing(List<rectangle> _main_list)
        {
            int _answer_count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < _main_list.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int k = i + 1; k < _main_list.Count; k++)
                {
                    List<int> list_of_X = new List<int>();
                    List<int> list_of_Y = new List<int>();

                    list_of_X.Add(_main_list[i]._x_left);
                    list_of_X.Add(_main_list[i]._x_right);
                    list_of_X.Add(_main_list[k]._x_left);
                    list_of_X.Add(_main_list[k]._x_right);

                    list_of_Y.Add(_main_list[i]._y_left);
                    list_of_Y.Add(_main_list[i]._y_right);
                    list_of_Y.Add(_main_list[k]._y_left);
                    list_of_Y.Add(_main_list[k]._y_right);

                    if (list_of_X[0] >= list_of_X[3] || list_of_X[2] >= list_of_X[1]
                        || list_of_Y[3] <= list_of_Y[0] || list_of_Y[1] <= list_of_Y[2])
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    list_of_X.Sort();
                    list_of_Y.Sort();                  

                    _answer_count += (list_of_X[1] - list_of_X[2]) * (list_of_Y[1] - list_of_Y[2]);                    
                    var temp = _main_list[i];
                    temp._crossing = true;
                    _main_list[i] = temp;
                    temp = _main_list[k];
                    temp._crossing = true;
                    _main_list[k] = temp;
                }
            }

            return _answer_count;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<rectangle> _main_list = new List<rectangle>();
            string _input_line = " ";

            while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_input_line))
            {
                _input_line = Console.ReadLine();
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_input_line))
                    break;
                string[] splitted = _input_line.Split('#', '@', ',', ':', 'x');
                rectangle _item;
                _item._id = Convert.ToInt32(splitted[1]);
                _item._x_left = Convert.ToInt32(splitted[2].Trim());
                _item._y_left = Convert.ToInt32(splitted[3]);
                _item._x_right = Convert.ToInt32(splitted[4].Trim()) + _item._x_left;
                _item._y_right = Convert.ToInt32(splitted[5]) + _item._y_left;
                _item._crossing = false;
                _main_list.Add(_item);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(_sum_of_crossing(_main_list));
            Console.WriteLine();

            for (int i = 0; i < _main_list.Count; i++)
            {
                if (_main_list[i]._crossing == false)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(_main_list[i]._id);
                }
            }

                Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Если кратко то считываем прямоугольники ,пробегаемся по всем без повторений,если пересекаются то считаем площадь пересечения и прибавляем к `_answer_count` и у обоих прямоугольников `_crossing` присваиваем `true`, если не пересекаются - идем дальше.Все просто.

При небольших данных все нормально работает и площадь корректно считается.

Но когда беру много прямоугольников то площадь высчитывается неверно.

Например , https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HS5mzRcbyylOIfThSCNYwisl2zHFLGiL/view

При использовании тестовых данных ответом будет: 104241 для первой части, #806 для второй, а у меня в первой части задания выводится 171109 (хотя вторая часть задания выводит верно 806)
[image: неверный вывод]

**Не понимаю** где ошибка, может быть кто-нибудь догадается и подскажет мне? очень уж интересно

**UPDATE 1**
Код с использованием сканирующей прямой

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace ConsoleApp5
{
    class Program
    {
        class Segment : IComparable<Segment>
        {
            public int xl, xr, y, type, id;
            public bool crossing;
            public Segment(int xl, int xr, int y, int type, int id)
            {
                this.xl = xl;
                this.xr = xr;
                this.y = y;
                this.type = type;
                this.id = id;
                crossing = false;
            }

            public int CompareTo(Segment obj)
            {
                if (this.y > obj.y)
                    return 1;
                if (this.y < obj.y)
                    return -1;
                else
                    return 0;
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> x = new List<int>();
            List<Segment> seg = new List<Segment>();
            string _input_line = " ";
            int n = 0;
            int _sum_pryamo = 0;
            while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_input_line))
            {
                _input_line = Console.ReadLine();
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_input_line))
                    break;
                string[] splitted = _input_line.Split('#', '@', ',', ':', 'x');

                int id = Convert.ToInt32(splitted[1]);
                int x1 = Convert.ToInt32(splitted[2].Trim());//+
                int y1 = Convert.ToInt32(splitted[3]) + Convert.ToInt32(splitted[5]);
                int x2 = Convert.ToInt32(splitted[4].Trim()) + x1;
                int y2 = Convert.ToInt32(splitted[3]);
                _sum_pryamo += Convert.ToInt32(splitted[4].Trim()) * Convert.ToInt32(splitted[5]);
                x.Add(x1);
                x.Add(x2);

                Segment item_low = new Segment(x1, x2, y1, 1, id);
                Segment item_high = new Segment(x1, x2, y2, -1, id);
                seg.Add(item_low);
                seg.Add(item_high);
                n++;
            }

            x.Sort();
            seg.Sort();
            int answer = 0;

            for (int i = 1; i < 2 * n; ++i)
            {
                int prevY = 0, cnt = 0;

                for (int j = 0; j < 2 * n; ++j)
                {
                    if (seg[j].xr <= x[i - 1] || seg[j].xl >= x[i])
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (cnt == 0)
                    {
                        prevY = seg[j].y;
                    }
                    cnt += seg[j].type;
                    if (cnt == 0)
                    {
                        answer += (seg[j].y - prevY) * (x[i] - x[i - 1]);

                    }

                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine(_sum_pryamo - answer);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А как учитываются пересечения трёх и более прямоугольников? Вообще это классическая задача вычислительной геометрии (см. Шеймос и Препарата)

Comment: То есть вы имеете ввиду 3+ прямоугольников которые пересекаются в одном месте?

Comment: Да, именно так. Если такие участки есть, и их площадь учитывается несколько раз - результат будет завышен.

Comment: Да, действительно, вы правы.
Может быть знаете как избежать этого?

Answer (score 2):

Эту задачу можно решить с использованием метода сканирующей прямой (sweep line algorithm) непрямым образом.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нетрудно найти реализацию получения площади объединения прямоугольников ([три](https://informatics.mccme.ru/mod/resource/view.php?id=39111) [случайные](https://tryalgo.org/en/geometry/2016/06/25/union-of-rectangles/) [ссылки](https://www.hackerearth.com/ru/practice/math/geometry/line-sweep-technique/tutorial/)).

Edit: Следующее неверно, тоже не учитывает множественные пересечения:
Если из общей площади всех прямоугольников вычесть площадь объединения - получим площадь пересечения.

Comment: Я попробовал сделать как вы посоветовали, но ответ все равно больше ожидаемого. Как я понял такой способ не учитывает то, что несколько прямоугольников (3 и более) могут пересекаться в одном месте.

Comment: А есть возможность проверить на своём наборе? Например, сделать три прямоугольника высотой 1, шириной 3, и с левой координатой 0, 1, 2. Пересечение по моей интерпретации (области, покрытые 2 и более раза) должно иметь площадь 3. Кроме того, можно посмотреть на R-деревья - есть ли в их арсенале нужный функционал.

Comment: При вашем наборе площадь получается 6. Сверху добавил акутуальный код

Comment: Хм, похоже, что я ошибаюсь с этим подходом - умозрительно должно получиться 9-5=4, а истинное пересечение  - 3